# Nested associative array as object

Tags: php

I'm trying to access a nested associative array
as object

```
function multiArrayToObject(array $array){

   if(!is_string(key($array))){
        throw new Exception('Invalid associative array'); 
    }
    $root = new ArrayObject($array,ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    foreach($array as $value){
       if(is_array($value)){
            multiArrayToObject($value);
       }
       else{
            return $root;
       }
    }
    return $root;
}

$array = array('user' => array('data'=>array('name'=>'bob')));


$data = multiArrayToObject($array);



var_dump($data->user->data);
```

but it doesn't work.

Could you help me, please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article outlining how to cast a multi dimensional array to an object: http://www.richardcastera.com/2009/07/06/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass/

Comment: $array = (object) array('user' => array('data'=>array('name'=>'bob')));
var_dump($array->user->data);
///Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: I could have sworn I've done that before.  Either way I edited my answer with somebody else's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want this, but I think this should fix it:

```
foreach($array as &$value){ // $value needs to be a reference to be able to change it
   if(is_array($value)){
        $value = multiArrayToObject($value); // you need to store the result
   }
   else{
        return $root; // i left this in, i'm not sure what it's for
   }
} unset($value); // this is recommended because of the & above
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
json_decode(json_encode($array_instance))
```

https://meet.google.com/linkredirect?authuser=0&dest=http%3A%2F%2Fsandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com%2Fcode%2Fd15d52ae1b110f50d4d8a1b9c3d67f45c2565a56